# Getting standard backgrounds of Teams provided by Microsoft

Tags: microsoft-teams

It is now possible to define a custom virtual background in Microsoft Teams.

But I love the standard integrated backgrounds provided by Microsoft.

Is it possible to recover the Microsoft-provided backgrounds as `.jpg` or `.png` files in "Program Files" or "Program Data" or some other folder?

Per an answer below, I've searched in:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds
```

... but this folder does not exist.

Comment: 100% clear, voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

If you have selected or used any background in the past, you can find them in the following folder:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds
```

If the folder is empty, select a background, then go back to the folder. The background image will be created.